# Ionic2 - invisible tabs - when generated from an observable

Tags: tabs, ionic2, invisible

My tabs.ts (simpilified) - data used to generated tabs with *ngFor is brought from php backend:

```
import ...

export interface Group {
        id: number;
        group: string;
    };

@Component( {
        template: `
    <ion-tabs #myTabs selectedIndex="0">
        <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of userGroups" [root]="page" [rootParams]="tab.id" [tabTitle]="tab.group" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
    `
    })

    export class GroupsTabsPage {
        userGroups: Group[];
        page: any = TabStudentsPage; 

        constructor( public app: App, public api: Api, public navParams: NavParams ) {

            this.api.getGroupsList()
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.userGroups = data;
                },
                err => {
                    this.app.getRootNav().push( LoginPage )
                }
                );

            //  ionViewDidEnter() {
            //  }

        }
    }
```

The result is invisible tabs. **But** when you hover your mouse ovet them, the cursor changes into 'hand' and you can click them. When clicked, the whole tabs bar becomes visible and all works as expected.

When I used @ViewChild to refer to the tabs elements, the interesting thing is that its 'length' property is always 0 (I checked in ionViewDidLoad event). Trying to select one of the tabs programatically also fails - they are like ghosts;)

Also when you place **at least one static** tab next to *ngFor ones in the template, all *ngFor ones show up but the static is always selected no matter what you select programatically or in selectedIndex property on tabs element.

Any idea guys? I've wasted three days..

Comment: Have you tried by using `this.content.resize()`? The [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/#resize) says _Tell the content to recalculate its dimensions. This should be called after dynamically adding headers, footers, or tabs._

Comment: I've added <ion-content> wrapping to my template and necessary import/@ViewChild stuff - no result..

The problem is that programatically the tabs element is empty. When I reference it ike @ViewChild( 'myTabs' ) tabRef: Tabs and then check console.log(this.tabRef.length()) it's 0 (in ionViewDidLoad). But physically there are 4 four tabs on the screen which you can click and pages load..

Answer (score 1):

that's a known bug, take a look at the element css, the subview's `.tabbar` has opacity of 0. I've just fixed it with a an override of opacity: 1. Ugly, but works...

Answer (score 0):

Creating ion-tab from observable (dynamically) has some bugs (duplicates, wrong rendering etc) I use a workaround to avoid it, it consist of removing and loading the ion-tabs runtime every time then observable changes.

**Parent template:**

```
<div #pluginTabContainer></div>
```

**Parent component:**

```
@ViewChild("pluginTabContainer", {read: ViewContainerRef}) pluginTabContainer:ViewContainerRef;
```

...

```
plugins$.subscribe((pluginTabs:Array<PluginTabType>) => { let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PluginTabContainerComponent); this.pluginTabContainer.clear(); this.pluginTabContainertRef = this.pluginTabContainer.createComponent(componentFactory); this.pluginTabContainertRef.instance.data = pluginTabs;
```

...

```
ngOnDestroy() { this.pluginTabContainertRef.destroy(); }
```

**Loaded ion-tabs template:**

```
<ion-tabs> <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of data" [root]="'PluginTabPage'" [rootParams]="tab"></ion-tab> </ion-tabs>
```

**Loaded ion-tabs component (getting parameter):**

```
@Input() data: PluginTabType;
```

Hope will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue during development and I was able to solve this by making ngOninit async and calling a timeout to set the selected tab.

view

```
 <ion-tabs #ctrlPanelTabs class="tabs-basic">
        <ion-tab *ngFor="let appTab of appTabs" tabTitle={{appTab.name}} [root]="rootPage"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
```

1) ngOninit is async

2) this.ctrlPanelTabs.select(0); is set inside a timeout function

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Tabs } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AppSettings } from '../../common/app.config';
import { AppTab } from '../../models/app-tab';
import { AppTabService } from '../../services/app-tab.service';
import { PanelTabComponent } from './panel-tab';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-control-panel',
    templateUrl: 'control-panel.html',
    providers: [AppTabService]
})
export class ControlPanelPage implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild("ctrlPanelTabs") ctrlPanelTabs: Tabs;

    appTabs: AppTab[] = [];
    message: string;
    rootPage = PanelTabComponent;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        private appTabService: AppTabService) {

        console.log("Control Panel Page : Constructor called..");
    }

    async ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Control Panel Page : Entering ngOninit..");
        await this.loadAppTabs();
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.ctrlPanelTabs.select(0);
        }, 100);
        console.log("Control Panel Page : Exiting ngOninit..");
    }

    async loadAppTabs() {
        console.log("Control Panel Page : Entering loadAppTabs..");
        await this.appTabService.getAppTabsHierarchyBySlaveDeviceId(AppSettings.selSlaveDeviceId)
            .then((response: any) => {
                this.appTabs = JSON.parse(response.result);
                console.log(this.appTabs);
                console.log("Control Panel Page : Exiting loadAppTabs..");
            });
    }

}
```